# Error while installing Thym in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When I install THyM in Eclipse, this error occurs:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Hybrid Mobile Application Development Tools 0.2.0.201503172021 (org.eclipse.thym.feature.feature.group 0.2.0.201503172021)
  Missing requirement: Hybrid Mobile App. Dev. Core 0.2.0.201503172021 (org.eclipse.thym.core 0.2.0.201503172021) requires 'bundle com.google.gson [2.1.0,3.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Hybrid Mobile Application Development Tools 0.2.0.201503172021 (org.eclipse.thym.feature.feature.group 0.2.0.201503172021)
    To: org.eclipse.thym.core [0.2.0.201503172021]
```

How can I fix it? Does anything need to be installed beforehand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This update site has a bundle com.google.gson:

```
Eclipse Code Recommenders Update Site
http://download.eclipse.org/recommenders/updates/stable/
```

Add it (just add, you don't need to install anything directly from it).  Install THyM using its update site:

```
THyM Update Site
http://download.eclipse.org/thym/releases/latest/
```

Comment: You can also download the Eclipse IDE for Java Developers and install THyM on it.

Answer (score 0):

I had an analogue problem in installing today's latest version (2.0.2), cause it required jgit 3.0.0 - 5.0.0 and I had 5.0.4.
I resolved by installing the latest snapshot build (2.1.0): you can read the repository URLs at https://wiki.eclipse.org/THyM